# How do I handle dynamically generated database tables in Phalcon?

Tags: phalcon

I'm creating a web application for our underwriting manager to create and test her rating schemes for various insurance products.

The editor allows the user to add and remove steps in the calculation process, and each such step can be dependent on several different rating factors (age of driver, age of vehicle, etc.). The number of factors per step is not fixed so the first step may only depend on one rating factor while the next may depend on four different rating factors.

My implementation uses a database table to store each step in table with the following structure:

```
 id  | schemeId  | stepnumber  |  stepname  |  calculationtable
-----------------------------------------------------------------
     |           |             |            |
```

`id` is the primary key, `schemeId` is the ID of the scheme that this step belongs to, `stepnumber` is used to order the steps (they're re-orderable in the editor), `stepname` is just a label for the step, and `calculation table holds the name of the table that holds the actual rating factor information for this step.

Creating a model for this table in Phalcon is a doddle and works fine. The problem is the calculation table. When a new step is created a row is inserted in this steps table and a brand new table is created with a name like `scheme1step10`. The structure of this table is dynamic depending on the number of factors that this step depends on in the calculation. The editor will allow the user to add and remove rating factors to each step so the number of columns in each of these tables will be different and will change over time. As a result of the dynamic nature of these tables I am unable to see how I can create a model for them.

I had a previous version of this editor that I was experimenting with a few years ago that didn't use a framework and the data retrieval for this table looked like this:

```
public function getSteptable()
{
    $returnval=false;
    $result=mysql_query("SHOW COLUMNS FROM ".$this->getCalculationtable());
    if($result!=false)
    {
        for($loop=0;$loop<mysql_num_rows($result);$loop++)
        {
            $row=mysql_fetch_array($result);
            $colnames[$loop]=$row['Field'];
        }
        $rowsresult=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ".$this->getCalculationtable());
        if($rowsresult!=false)
        {
            for($loop=0;$loop<mysql_num_rows($rowsresult);$loop++)
            {
                $row=mysql_fetch_array($rowsresult);
                foreach($colnames as $colname)
                {
                    $returnval[$loop][$colname]=$row[$colname];
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return $returnval;
}
```

Please ignore the fact that this code uses the deprecated `mysql_` functions.

So my question is how can I recreate this kind of thing in Phalcon? It looks like I can't use PHQL since it seems to rely on a model existing for the table in question - I get an error `Model 'scheme1step1' could not be loaded` when I try `$steptable=$this->modelsManager->executeQuery("SELECT * FROM $steptablename")` (`$steptablename` is taken from another table and is originally generated by the application so should be safe from the possibility of SQL injection I think). Do I need to use raw SQL as shown [here](http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/phql.html#using-raw-sql) or does that rely on having an extant model too? Or am I going to need to create my own model that avoids Phalcon's ORM for these dynamic tables? And if that's the case can I use the DB connection stored in the DI container without causing any problems?

Answer (score 0):

That's very interesting problem.

I believe it should be possible to achieve with a "dynamic" Model, modelsManager and custom metaData strategy, though this is only my theory which may or may not work at all, or just lead you into the right directions.

---

1. Create an autoloader which will dynamically create a scheme1step1 class for you either by using eval() or something similar to Zend_CodeGenerator_Php_Class() - make it simple like :

   > eval('class scheme1step1 extends \Phalcon\Mvc\Model {} ');
2. Create a custom MetaData strategy similar to Introspection (maybe extend it) which will work as a "catch all" proxy object
3. If the strategy detects that a regular model's been invoked just pass it through to Introspection parent
4. If it detects scheme1step1 Model, instruct it appropriately about the table's columns map, maybe with \Phalcon\Db\Dialect\Mysql or again Introspection (depends on other needs)

Or just do steps 2,3,4 within step 1 :D
Good luck!

PS. I've stopped myself from commenting on the idea of dynamically "sharding" tables like this which doesn't look right, instead focused on the real problem